# tensorflowがVSCodeで認識されない

Tags: python, python3, vscode, tensorflow

`import tensorflow as tf` と記述すると上記のようなメッセージが表示されます。

```
Import "tensorflow" could not be resolved　（PylancereportMissingImports）
```

#### 試したこと

ターミナル(コマンドプロンプト)で `pip install tensorflow` を実行し、`pip show tensorflow` で仮想環境へのインストールへの確認は取れました。

`pip show tensorflow` の実行結果

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.10.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\katou\anaconda4\lib\site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, keras, keras-preprocessing, libclang, numpy, opt-einsum, packaging, protobuf, setuptools, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, typing-extensions, wrapt
Required-by:
```

その後、再起動しましたが状況は改善されません。インタプリタはPython 3.10.4 64-bitを選択しています。
プログラムを実行した際のエラーメッセージはこちらです。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

VSCodeをアンインストールし、再インストールすることを検討していますが何か解決策に心当たりある方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

また、下に示すのは現在のVSCodeの画面です。また、下記のsetting.jsonではAnacondaの保存場所が恐らく実際のものと異なる場所で保存されているのですが、こちらは関係ありますでしょうか？知見のある方ご助言お願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: メッセージは表示されても実行自体はできるかと思いますができませんか？それとも実行はできるがメッセージが表示されるのが嫌なので表示されないようにしたいということでしょうか？

Comment: はい。実行ができないです。tensorflowやmatplotlibも同じように読み込んでくれません。モジュールは全てインストール済みです。

Comment: 「はい。実行ができないです。」ということは”ModuleNotFoundError”が発生したということでしょうか？エラーメッセージを追記されると回答がつきやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: 丁寧なご指摘ありがとうございます。ModuleNotFoundErrorです。エラー文は質問に追加させて頂きました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: VSCodeのPythonインタープリターはAnacondaのbase環境になっていますか？

Comment: ターミナルではconda activateで仮想環境を実行していますが、インタープリターの設定はこれでできていますでしょうか？

Comment: VSCodeのバージョンが分かりませんが、VSCodeの右下にtensorflowをインストールしたAnacondaの仮想環境名が表示されてますか？　⇒　画像を見るとなってませんね。 3.10.4 と表示されているところをダブルクリックするとインタープリター選択できるかと思うのでtensorflowをインストールしたものを選択すれば良いです。

Comment: 無知で申し訳ないです、、ありがとうございます。解決しました！